# Rails: blank page - no errors or stack trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to fix a bug in the Rails app I'm developing, and I keep getting a blank screen with no errors. I haven't found anything helpful in `development.log`, either (though it does show queries being run and such).

Finally, I started to wonder if it's somehow set not to show errors anymore. I tried commenting out a necessary route, and sure enough, **I got a blank page instead of the error and stack trace I expected.**

**What might cause this?**

(I wondered if maybe I'm accidentally running production mode and errors aren't supposed to show then, but `development.log` is being appended, and if I open `script/console` and echo `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`, it says development.)

Comment: Sounds like you're on the trail to find the missing error and stack trace...

A couple questions: If you view the source of the blank page, is there non-visible content there? Do the HTTP headers returned to the browser give an "OK" 200 status or an error?

Comment: @ewall - source is also empty. Status is 200 OK.

Comment: don't suppose there's any chance you could put the code on github so that people can download it and test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How I broke it, how I fixed it, and how I learned my lesson

I figured out the problem while lying in bed this morning, and it boils down to "I did something stupid."  (Doesn't it always?)

#### The smart part

First, the smart part: I followed [some neat advice about setting up access control and permissions](http://pivotallabs.com/users/nick/blog/articles/272-access-control-permissions-in-rails). It gives you some great a great syntax for saying what's allowed, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @photo, :confirm => "Really delete this photo?", :method => :delete if current_user.can_delete?(@photo)%>
```

(The `current_user` bit comes from the Restful-authentication plugin.)

The author also shows how to handle the case where a user tries to type in a URL for which you haven't given them a link. It involves setting up a special exception class, which subclasses `StandardError`, and handling it with something like a `401.html` - access denied.

#### The stupid part

What I did that was stupid was **I followed his example blindly.** He shows this:

```
def rescue_action(e)
    case e
    when SecurityTransgression
      head :forbidden
    end
end
```

...which handles the `SecurityTransgression` fine, but **breaks the default error handling in Rails**. (I'm sure the author knows this and dealt with it, but he didn't discuss it.)

#### The solution

The solution was to add two lines:

```
def rescue_action(e)
    case e
    when SecurityTransgression
      head :forbidden
    else
      super
    end
end
```

The "else super" part says "if I haven't specified anything here, let the inherited `rescue_action` method handle it."

Now I'm getting the correct stack trace for my original problem, and will proceed to troubleshoot it.

The lesson: be careful when you mess with exception handling, and make sure the default case still works!

Comment: you might wanna change that to a `return super`, just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your default route and make sure the view isn't just empty.

Comment: The view definitely isn't empty. I can comment out part of it and make the page show, but I think I should be getting errors when the problem code is running, and I KNOW I should get an error when I deliberately break a route.

Comment: Try replacing config/environments/development.rb with the default and see if that works.

Comment: It sure seems like it's just the dev env error handler that's failing to show. I hope for your sake that the config swap helps!

Comment: I figured this out - if you're interested, see my answer. Thanks for your help!